# What's the best way to position an svg in order to make it mobile friendly & work across multiple screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, svg, mobile

Ideally, I'd like to have this svg at the right side of my screen, and become mobile friendly. I was looking into media queries, but I realized I would have to code the exact position for every different media size. Let me know if there is an efficient way of making the svg position mobile friendly.
Here is the code:

```
 <!-- side design neon pink -->
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="87.43" height="867.24" viewBox="0 0 87.43 867.24">
        <defs>
          <clipPath id="clip-path">
            <rect width="87.43" height="867.24" fill="none"/>
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <g id="Repeat_Grid_1" data-name="Repeat Grid 1" clip-path="url(#clip-path)">
          <g transform="translate(-287.868 -0.348)">
            <path id="wave_2_" data-name="wave (2)" d="M-40.233,309.629l67.77-59.788C55,217.986,69.618,180.03,124.543,186.934,179.469,193.353,274.7,243.422,329.627,237c54.925-6.9,130.937-40.482,185.862-53.806s88.765-3.969,143.69,27.886c54.926,32.339,109.851,32.339,137.314,32.339h27.463V359.7H.074Z" transform="matrix(-0.017, -1, 1, -0.017, 124.954, 830.456)" fill="#f638dc"/>
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
```

Any help/comment is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: We need [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you out. Add the full code and provide more information about desired result. Now it's hard to understand what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: I got it, thank you for the comment

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the width and height of the SVG.

Wrap SVG in parent container `<div class =" container ">`

And give it width and height in relative units.

This will make your application responsive.

```css
.container {
width:5vw;
height:5vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<!-- side design neon pink -->
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 87.43 867.24"  style="border:1px solid">
        <defs>
          <clipPath id="clip-path">
            <rect width="87.43" height="867.24" fill="none"/>
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <g id="Repeat_Grid_1" data-name="Repeat Grid 1" clip-path="url(#clip-path)">
          <g transform="translate(-287.868 -0.348)">
            <path id="wave_2_" data-name="wave (2)" d="M-40.233,309.629l67.77-59.788C55,217.986,69.618,180.03,124.543,186.934,179.469,193.353,274.7,243.422,329.627,237c54.925-6.9,130.937-40.482,185.862-53.806s88.765-3.969,143.69,27.886c54.926,32.339,109.851,32.339,137.314,32.339h27.463V359.7H.074Z" transform="matrix(-0.017, -1, 1, -0.017, 124.954, 830.456)" fill="#f638dc"/>
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: @Daisy If the answer was useful to you, please do not forget to mark it

Answer (score 1):

I added a class to my svg, then I added translate (im positioning for iphone x 375px
width):

```
    .neon_pink_svg {
    transform: translate(287.87px, -32px);
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: To position fixed element on the screen use `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left`, you do not want to use `transform` for positioning